# How big can the application's IsolatedStorage be on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

How much can be stored, at most, in the app's IsolatedStorage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no limit on WP8 for the IsolatedStorage.

But of course you'll get an exception if you run out of space when writing new data, so you have to handle that properly.

See at the bottom of that page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769544%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

> Windows Phone applications do not have a limit on the quota for
>   storage on disk. The quota APIs reflect this, and GetUserStoreForSite
>   is not available.