# DB usage in windows phone

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Can anybody help me,

I have the following questions about db in windows phone, I have made a search and couldn't get nothing helpful.

1)if I use a db(like SQL-lite) or some other db structure, where the files will be stored.

2)If they stored in Isolated Storage only, what is the memory limit(files size) I can use with that db.

3)if they not stored in Isolated Storage, where they have stored and what is the memory limit(files size) I can use with that db.

4)Can I set a SD card or external memory card path to my sql-lite db files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) File will be stored in Isolated Storage

2) App memory limits and file sizes are different things. For app memory see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681682%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). For disk size you'll be limited by the OS but theoretically it'll be 4GB. There's rarely a good reason to have a database that big in a consumer app though. You'll also be unable to include a file so large in the XAP when distributed.

3) n/a

4) No. The SD card can only be read from, not written to in, 3rd party apps, on Windows Phone 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing for windows phone i would recommend using linq to sql as illustrated in detail in 
[Local Database for windows phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx). Files will be stored in isolated storage.

As far as limit on file sizes in isolated storage is concerned, there is no limit [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192968/how-big-can-the-applications-isolatedstorage-be-on-windows-phone-8). So you should store DB files on isolated storage only as memory cards are not available on all phones.

Answer (score 0):

1. On Production - in isolated Storage only. While developing, you can also store files in application installation folder.
2. No limits
3. See point 1
4. No, SD and external storage are limited to very few multimedia files.